# Why isn't this valid Java?

Tags: java, optimization, coding-style, code-snippets

Surely this should be valid Java? Have I got the syntax slightly wrong?

```
return (url != null) ? url : (throw new NotFoundException("No url"));
```

If not I suppose I'd have to do this:

```
if(url == null)
    throw new NotFoundException("No url");
return url;
```

Anyone have anything more succinct?

Comment: The throw clause does not meet the definition of an "expression".

Comment: `throw` is a statement, it cannot be used in an expression. It's like trying to say `true ? "hi" : boolean var;`

Comment: And if you want something "more succinct" just do `if (url == null) throw new NotFOundException("No url"); return url;` (One line)

Comment: your idea of succinct is not good coding style in my opinion because it reduces readability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're not fulfilling the return:

```
return <comparison> ? <value1> :(else) <value2>
```

In your case, you're fulfilling the `value1` but not `value2` and instead you're throwing a new exception.

Your actual first code would be translated to

```
if (url != null) {
    return url;
} else {
    return throw new NotFoundException("No url"); //makes sense?
}
```

Comment: I'm saying return something 'else' throw an exception

Comment: @Blundell -- the `?:` construct is not an if/else statement.

Comment: Right, right it's my understanding of ternary, it's used for assignment and I can't assign the return value to a throws clause. I was thinking of it just as a short hand if else. Thanks

Comment: There are ways you could fake it, but it's not worth it -- the simple `if` is easier to understand and less error-prone.

Answer (score 4):

The ternary operator takes (as is clear from its name) three arguments. The first is the comparison (the value of which is converted to a boolean). The second two must share a type (or be convertible to the same type), namely the type that is the type of the entire statement.

The problem in your code is that `throw new NotFoundException("No url");` is a statement. Statements don't have a value and as such, do not share a type with anything else. That's the reason why statements aren't allowed in the second or third argument of the ternary operator. It doesn't matter here because the part that's a statement happens to be a throw statement, but that's coincidental. For the ternary operator to make sense in general, the two values need to have the same value and thus can't be statements.

(Do note that in Java, all objects inherit from java.lang.Object and java has special (and complex) rules for conversion if one of the two values in a `ConditionalExpression` (as it's called in the language definition) is a primitive, so if neither of the two arguments is a statement, it's going to work.)

Comment: While I was typing, Luiggi edited his answer to include basically the same thing (in code form), but I decided to post anyway because the approach of my explanation is a little different

Comment: No, what you put in there must be ? expr : expr. `throw` is not an expression so you cannot use ternanry operator even if you had two throws (which share a type, ... well not cos statements don't evaluate to any type or value)

Comment: @Esailija: a statement without a type and another statement without a type do not share any types. Just like how the cross-section of two empty collections is an empty collection, not a non-empty collection.

Comment: Statements don't have a type, they don't evaluate to any type or value or anything. You are saying "Statement without a type", as if there was a statement with a type?

Comment: @Esailija: I know that, but you said two statements had the same type, which is just plain untrue

Comment: @Esailija: I edited the answer to basically say the same thing, but to be technically more correct. Are you happier with the answer now?

Answer (score 2):

It's not valid because it doesn't conform to the BNF:

```
Expression:
    Expression1 [ AssignmentOperator Expression1 ]

 Expression1:
    Expression2 [ Expression1Rest ]

Expression1Rest:
    ? Expression : Expression1
```

Answer (score 2):

There **is** a way around this, if you really, really like succintness (I do!). Declare a method

```
public static <T> T trhow(RuntimeException e) {
  throw e;
}
```

Then just write `trhow(new MyException());` instead of `throw new MyException();`. How well this will infer your type in the middle of a ternary operator, I'm not sure, but maybe you can get away with a concrete instead of generic type.

Also, if you want this to work for a checked exception, it's going to be even more trouble. There is an idiom allowing you to throw any checked exception without declaring it, but that would defeat the point of it being checked in the first place.

Comment: Nice! I'd use this if it wasn't just to benefit my own self indulgence, but I think other people reading my code might think WTF :-)

Comment: In the defense of this idiom it can be argued that the intent of the programmer is dead obvious. I say let them learn :)